Could someone check my work? (1st order ODEs)
Question
Solve
$$ 
2x + \frac{2y(1+x^2)}{1+y^2}y' = 0 \quad y(1) = 1\tag{1}
$$
Work
Let $ r(x) = 1+x^2 $ and $ s(y) = 1+y^2 $, then $(1)$ can be rewritten as
\begin{align}
&r'(x) + \frac{s'(y)r(x)}{s(y)}y' = 0 \newline
&=r'(x)s(y) + s'(y)r(x)y' = 0 \newline
&\implies y' = -\frac{s(y)}{s'(y)}\frac{r'(x)}{r(x)} \newline
\end{align}
Therefore, this is a separable equation and the solution can be found through direct integration. Representing y' as $\frac{dy}{dx}$ gives us
\begin{align}
\frac{s'(y)}{s(y)} dy &= \frac{r'(x)}{r(x)} dx \newline
\frac{2y}{1+y^2} dy &= -\frac{2x}{1+x^2}dx \newline
\int{\frac{2y}{1+y^2}dy} &= -\int{\frac{2x}{1+x^2}dx} \newline
 \ln|1+y^2| &= - \ln|1+x^2| + c
\end{align}
Since $1+y^2 > 0 \\\; \forall \\\; y$ and $1+x^2 > 0 \\\; \forall \\\; x$ we can drop the absolute value signs.
\begin{align}
 \ln(1+y^2) &= - \ln(1+x^2) \newline
 \ln(1+y^2) &=  \ln(1+x^2)^{-1} \\\; \textrm{(multiply both sides by e)} \newline
1+y^2 &= \frac{1}{1+x^2} \newline
y^2 &= \frac{1}{1+x^2} + c - 1 
\end{align}
Since $c$ is a constant and $c-1$ is a constant, we can wrap the $-1$ up with the $c$. Thus, we get
\begin{align}
y^2 &= \frac{1}{1+x^2} + c \newline
y^2 &= \frac{1 + c(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} \newline
y &= \pm \frac{\sqrt{1+c(1+x^2)}}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
\end{align}
Since our I.C. specifies that $y(1) = 1$ we drop the minus sign from our expression and we solve
\begin{align}
1 &= \frac{\sqrt{1 + 2c}}{\sqrt{2}} \newline
1 &= \frac{1+2c}{2} \newline
2 &= 1+2c \iff 2c = 1 \implies c = \frac{1}{2}
\end{align}
Therefore, $y = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \frac{1+x^2}{2}}{1+x^2}} = \sqrt{\frac{3 + x^2}{2+2x^2}}$. Thank you.

You can always check your result. Substitute $y$ and $y'$ into the ODE and see if the LHS equals the RHS.

You need to add constant right after integration
$$
\ln(1+y^2)=A-\ln(1+x^2)
\\\Rightarrow 1+y^2={C\over1+x^2}
$$
using initial conditions
$$
y=\sqrt{{2\over1+x^2}-1}
$$

Is $A - ln(1+x^2) = \frac{A}{1+x^2}$? Does this assume that A is a logarithm?

Nevermind. It's from $e^{A - ln(1+x^2)} = e^Ae^{ln(1+x^2)^{-1}} = \frac{e^A}{1+x^2} = \frac{A}{1+x^2}$.

@Calum removed the confusing bit tq for bringing it up
